# How to get the value of a field from Lambda expression for ForEach()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, foreach

I have a mapping json which looks like below.

```
{
  "MappingFields": [
    {
      "ID": "M1",
      "Name": "John",
      "Role": "Developer"
    },
    {
      "ID": "M2",
      "Name": "Peter",
      "Role": "Tester"
    }]
}
```

I need compare the `ID` field with the one I receive in input and get the corresponding values of `Name` and `Role`. I achieved the same through below.

```
string id = "M2"; \\input value
List<MappingField> mappedData = mappingFields.MappingFields.ToList(); \\MappingField is a data model
string name = string.Empty;
string role = string.Empty;
foreach(var item in mappedData) 
{
    if(item.ID == id)
    {
        name = item.Name;
        role = item.Role;
    }
}
```

I believe this can be done in a more easy way through lambda expression. And below is what I tried.

```
name = mappedData.Where(o => o.ID == id).Select(p => p.Name).ToString();
role = mappedData.Where(o => o.ID == id).Select(p => p.Role).ToString();
```

But I am not getting the value in the variable. Instead, I am getting this.

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Test.Lib.Model.MappingField,System.String]

What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `var result = mappedData.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == id)` then you can call `result.Name`, and `result.Role`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are trying to cast object to string.
You could use
`name = mappedData.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == id).Name;`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert an enumerable to string using `.ToString()`, this will not work

You could just query for the mapping.

```
var result = mappedData.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == id);

if(result != null) // did it find anything?
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Role);       
}
```